# AngularJS ng-include templates not loading in Phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova, include, angularjs

I'm building an iOS Phonegap app that uses AngularJS.

I've got some `ng-includes` inside an `ng-switch` that change the style of some list items depending on the item's category.

```
        <div 
            ng-repeat="i indata"
            ng-include="src='partials/card.html'""
        >
        </div>
```

Inside the *partials/card.html* file, is the switch:

```
<div 
ng-switch on="i.group"
>
<div ng-switch-when="Music">
    <div ng-include="src='partials/card_details/'+i.category+'.html'"
    ></div>
</div>  
<div ng-switch-when="Film"
    ng-include="src='partials/card_details/buy.html'"></div>        
<!-- default, load group -->
<div ng-switch-default ng-include="src='partials/card_details/'+i.group+'.html'"
></div>
```

This all works perfectly in Chrome on my desktop browser, but when I run my Phonegap app, using the same sym-linked www folder as the pages running in Chrome, everything loads *except* the partials inside the switch statement.

I don't get any errors in the Xcode console, I've tried adding "/" to the start of the *src* as I've had problems with paths from the root in Phonegap, but what I don't get is why the *partials/card.html* loads and *not* the ones inside *partials/card_details*

Any ideas?

Comment: Taking a look at this, maybe Angular is being fussy about the syntax, would something like `<div ng-switch-when="Film"><ng-include src="'partials/cart_details/buy.html'"></ng-include></div>` work?

Comment: `<ng-include src="'partials/{{card.type}}_details/buy.html'"></ng-include></div>` - is that how I'm supposed to put variable contents into that property?

Comment: No luck with that technique, works fine in Chrome, fails in the Phonegap app

Answer (score 1):

Is this because the ng-include in the line below has double quotes on the end of it:

```
   <div 
        ng-repeat="i indata"
        ng-include="src='partials/card.html'""
    >
    </div>
```

Comment: +1 Nice observation. This question is currently the sole reason I'm hesitating to make the switch to angular. This definitely seems like a possible reason.

Comment: That's more likely to be a typo in the question. I'll have a look. I've currently used a work around to avoid having embedded includes, inside another include. @dk123 Angular is brilliant and worth the difficult learning curve, this particular problem I've only found inside webkit view on the iPhone - in Chrome on my desktop it works perfectly well.

Comment: @Skeater Thanks for the update. I'm mainly developing web apps lately though and if something isn't working on the iPhone that fact makes me somewhat hesitant. Could you perhaps post up the work around you've mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the _ (underscore) from the file names. I remember seeing a hint about this.

```
<div ng-include="src='partials/cardDetails/'+i.category+'.html'"></div>
```

instead of

```
<div ng-include="src='partials/card_details/'+i.category+'.html'"></div>
```

EDIT:

I have also discovered that ng-include is case sensitive when it comes to file names.

Comment: Please, add more info in your answer (put an example, properly formatted)